# Can not exclude MongoAutoConfiguration in Springboot java config

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to exclude MongoAutoConfuguration in my Springboot application.

**application.properties**

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
    spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb://localhost/test
    spring.data.mongodb.host1=mongodb://localhost/test1
```

**Main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I haven't receive any error. But the database got connected in which db assigned to the spring.data.mongodb.host.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
```